# Beautiful Soup won't let me edit text to fit only the 2 keyword lists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello I've been trying to write code that prints only positive and negative titles from this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx6TVdZU0FtVnVHZ0pWVXlnQVAB?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'

##company_list = ['apple', 'microsoft', 'google', 'amazon', 'tesla', 'berkshire', 'unitedhealth', 'nvidia', 'meta', 'johnson']

positive_list = ['quick work', 'move ahead', 'saves', 'save']

negative_list = ['loss', 'buys', 'buy', 'falsely', 'revoke', 'hot water']
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

titles = soup.find_all('h4', class_='ipQwMb ekueJc RD0gLb')

for title in titles:
    all_titles = title.text.strip()
```

All methods seem to give me a blank shell, how can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx6TVdZU0FtVnVHZ0pWVXlnQVAB?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
titles = soup.find_all('h4', class_='ipQwMb ekueJc RD0gLb')
all_titles = [title.text.strip() for title in titles]

positive_list = ['quick work', 'move ahead', 'saves', 'save']
negative_list = ['loss', 'buys', 'buy', 'falsely', 'revoke', 'hot water']
pos_titles = [t for t in all_titles if any(pw in t for pw in positive_list)]
neg_titles = [t for t in all_titles if any(pw in t for pw in negative_list)]
```

Then `pos_titles` is

```
["Musk says Twitter deal could move ahead with 'bot' info",
 'Caught on camera: N.J. sandwich shop worker saves choking customer',
 'Caught on camera: New Jersey sandwich shop worker Danielle Buccelli saves choking customer',
 'PrimoHoagies employee in N.J. saves woman choking on sandwich']
```

and `neg_titles` is

```
['Amazon agrees to buy iRobot, putting robot vacuum makers on alert',
 'Berkshire Hathaway posts $43.8 billion loss as stock holdings tumble',
 'Berkshire Hathaway reports operating earnings surge, but posts big investment loss amid market rout',
 "Warren Buffett's Berkshire reins in stock purchases and books $43.8bn loss",
 'California regulator claims Tesla falsely advertised Autopilot, Full Self-Driving',
 'Tesla is in hot water with California DMV over its Autopilot and self-driving claims',
 'Opinion: Why a recession might not mean huge job losses',
 'Pfizer in talks to buy Global Blood Therapeutics for roughly $5bn',
 'Toyota will buy back your recalled bZ4X EV',
 "Realtors say it's now more of a buyers market"]
```